# ¿Cuál es la traducción correcta para las palabras "pack" y "bundles" inglés > español?

Tags: discusión

En la [documentación de Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html) usan tres palabras que en español podrían traducirse como "paquete":

- `package`
- `pack`
- `bundle`

Generalmente en informática se usa `package`, la cual se traduce como "paquete", ¿cuál sería la traducción correcta para `pack` y para `bundle`.

Si las traduzco como "paquete", habría dificultad en textos como este:

> A common practice when developing Symfony applications is to install
> **packages** (Symfony calls them **bundles**) that provide ready-to-use features. **Packages** usually require some setup before
> using them (editing some file to enable the **bundle**, creating some file
> to add some initial config, etc.)

O como este:

> Symfony **Packs**
>
> Sometimes a single feature requires installing several **packages** and
> **bundles**. Instead of installing them individually, Symfony provides
> **packs**, which are Composer **metapackages** that include several
> dependencies.
>
> For example, to add debugging features in your application, you can
> run the `composer require --dev debug` command. This installs the
> `symfony/debug-pack`, which in turn installs several **packages** like
> `symfony/debug-bundle`, `symfony/monolog-bundle`, `symfony/var-dumper`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Mis sugerencias son:

- *package*: **paquete** o **módulo**
- *bundle*: este término es específico de Symfony, así que dudo que haya una  que sea la acertada frente a todas las posibles. Me  inclino por **bulto** o **atado**; otros sinónimos como *montón* o *pila* sólo confunden más, pues éstos ya están asignados para la traducción de otros términos existentes. De acuerdo a la documentación de Symfony, los *bundles* consisten prácticamente en carpetas con una estructura organizada particularmente para que sea tratado como un *plug-in*. El problema de traducirlo como *carpeta* o *plug-in* es que se pierde precisión semántica.
- *pack*: es un conjunto de paquetes, así que es una **biblioteca**

Answer (score 1):

Por experiencia, salvo excepciones, no es fácil adaptar algunas palabras que suelen utilizarse en informática al español, ya que no existe en este idioma una tradición lo suficientemente arraigada, como para adoptar términos propios y duraderos de forma habitual, pues al proceder aquellos del inglés muchas veces es mejor describirlos, dar un rodeo, utilizar giros, explicarlos de forma conjunta, adaptar al idioma español otros términos relacionados, mantenerlos entre paréntesis o inventarse palabras o acrónimos igualmente relacionados, con puntualización o aclaración a pie de página de porque se hace, y para que sirve, como una referencia que deje constancia. Espero que le ayude.

- Packages - Paquetes, Aplicaciones, Programa/s, Software, Componentes.
- Ejemplo de acrónimo para (bundle): "paquetes con funciones integradas (pafi)"
- Pack/Packs - Parche/Parches

**Traducción del texto con ejemplos con objeto de dar algunas ideas generales.**

> Una práctica común al desarrollar aplicaciones Symfony es instalar
> **un paquete de utilidades** (Symfony los llama **paquetes con funciones integradas** (*bundle*)) que brindan funciones listas para
> usar. **Estas aplicaciones** generalmente requieren alguna
> configuración antes de usarlas (editar algún archivo para habilitar
> **las funciones integradas** (*pafi*), crear algún archivo para agregar alguna
> configuración inicial, etc.)
>
> **Parches Symfony**
>
> A veces, una sola característica requiere la instalación de varios
> componentes y **parches**. En lugar de instalarlos individualmente,
> Symfony proporciona **parches**, que son metapaquetes (*pequeñas piezas de
> software que permiten agrupar la instalación de varios componentes junto con sus
> aplicaciones*) de Composer y que incluyen varias colecciones y directorios.
>
> Por ejemplo, para agregar funciones de depuración en su aplicación,
> puede ejecutar el comando composer require --dev debug. Esto instalará
> el **parche** de depuración de symfony que a su vez, instalará varios
> **archivos y componentes con funciones integradas** (pafi) como el symfony
> depurador (debug-bundle), el symfony monólogo (monolog-bundle), el
> symfony volcado de variables (var-dumper), etc.